# Access-Control-Allow-Originin multiple values with AJAX to PHP on Remote URL (same server)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know there are a ton of similar posts about this subject, but I have been at this almost full time for two days and tried & read about any possible solution i could find. None worked so I am trying to figure out if any other expert has an idea that might work.

I'm trying to call a PHP script on (fictional) websiteshop.net from websitedojo.com. It's done with an AJAX call and works fine on the native URL.

I'm transferring the program, but want to leave the backend scripts on the native/original URL. I'm getting the error that is well known and widely diuscussed:

> Failed to load https://websiteshop.net/cl/ajax-tst.php: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
>   'https://websitedojo.com, *', but only one is allowed. Origin
>   'https://websitedojo.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Plus, after clikcing the alert box:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://websiteshop.net/cl/ajax-tst.php with MIME type
>   application/json. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

I have tested so many things by now it is driving me insane. Below the part of an AJAX call, I tried all sorts of variations and combinations here. Whatever is commented, I tried as well without comments of course:

AJAX:

> ```
> $.ajax({
> url: "https://websiteshop.net/cl/ajax_tst.php", // Url to which the request is send
> // headers:{
>     // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
> // },
> type: "POST", // Type of request to be send, called as method
> data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
> //data: data,
> crossOrigin: true,
> dataType: 'jsonp',
> contentType: false, // The content type used when sending data to the server.
> cache: false, // To unable request pages to be cached
> processData: false, // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
> success: function (data) // A function to be called if request succeeds
> {
> ...
> ```

In htaccess I tried all combinations like these and others:

```
Options -Indexes
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://websitedojo.com, *"

#<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(websitedojo.com|other.nl)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
#    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
#    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
#</IfModule>
```

In the PHP file itself, I tried these combinations (also without https://):

```
header_remove('Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
// header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "https://websitedojo.com, *');
$allowed=array('https://websitedojo.com','https://www.websitedojo.com', 'https://websiteshop.net','http://localhost','http://127.0.0.1');
$origin=isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']:$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if(in_array($origin, $allowed)){
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$origin);
}else{
    exit(0);
}
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With');
header('P3P: CP="NON DSP LAW CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD HIS OUR DEL IND UNI PUR COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC IVD SAM IVA OTC"');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1');
```

This is the latest result from the headers.

Requestheaders:

```
Host: websiteshop.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: nl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://websitedojo.com/websiteshop/dynamic-and-crazy-engagement/
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------23129260416654
Content-Length: 297094
Origin: https://websitedojo.com
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 16 Oct 2018 10:53:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.37
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://websitedojo.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With
P3P: CP="NON DSP LAW CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD HIS OUR DEL IND UNI PUR COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC IVD SAM IVA OTC"
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1
Vary: User-Agent
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Are there any none-server related things I can try? Or can I run an SSH command to see my serversettings for the necessary settings?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Change `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://websitedojo.com, *"` to `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Comment: If only it were that easy. Tried that too, as the First attempt. That only changes it  to 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.

Comment: Because you have a header in htaccess and in PHP. You should remove the one in htaccess.

Comment: I'd love to say thanks you're right. But honestly, I wouldn't post this question if I'd not tried ALL those variations already. When i remove it from htaccess, it remains the same error as above.

Comment: Even when i remove it everywhere, I still get this same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved (with new issues but that's fine).

Apache and Nginx were each setting the same header, my host (thanks Mike) has removed the one from apache so only nginx is setting it now.